# Auto relaod after login

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I have a google login on my website, with an auto reload after the user is correctly logged in.

The problem is every time the user is browsing the website it is reloading the page.

So if he opens an article, it will load the page and the reload the page.

Here is my JS

```
    function onSuccess(googleUser) {
    var static_url = 'https://www.mywebsite.com/';
    
    gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function () {
        var request = gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get({
            'userId': 'me'
        });
        request.execute(function (resp) {
onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a></h3>';
</b>'+resp.id+'</p><p><b>Name: </b>'+resp.name+'</p><p><b>Email: </b>'+resp.email+'</p><p><b>Gender: </b>'+resp.gender+'</p><p><b>Locale: </b>'+resp.locale+'</p><p><b>Google Profile:</b> <a target="_blank" href="'+resp.link+'">click to view profile</a></p>';
            
            
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: static_url+'/deals/google_login',
                async: false,
                data: {email:resp.email,name:resp.name},
                success: function (result) {
                    $('.msg').removeClass('alert alert alert-danger');
                    $('.lmsg').show();
                    if(result == 'blocked'){
                        signOut();
                        $('.lmsg').addClass('alert alert-danger');
                        $('.lmsg').html('Your account is blocked');
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $('.lmsg').fadeOut('slow');
                        }, 3000);
                    }else{
                        
                        if( window.localStorage ){
                        if( !localStorage.getItem('firstLoad') ){
                            $('.lmsg').addClass('alert');
                            $('.lmsg').html('Successfully Logged In');
                            localStorage['firstLoad'] = true;
                            $('.lmsg').fadeOut('slow');
                            window.location.reload();
                        }else
                            localStorage.removeItem('firstLoad');
                        }

                    }
                }
            });            
        });
    });
}
```

If I remove the window.location.reload(); the issue is gone, but user get stuck on the login page, so I really need to reload the page after the user logged in. To redirect it to the front page and load his profile picture, name...

Does any one already face this issue? or have a solution?

Thank you

Comment: This has nothing to do with any of the tags you originally used. I've corrected them for you. Remember that Java and JavaScript are two different things. And this code you've posted does not touch your server-side PHP environment at all.

Comment: It seems though that you aren't following the google-documented process for logins involving a server side web app. This should be much more securely integrated with the backend using the authentication token. https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth